# How to create a notification in StackDriver filter with JsonPayload parameter

Tags: notifications, stackdriver

Create a email notification for specific JsonPayload value
severity => WARNING and JsonPayload reason: "FailedGetResourceMetric"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [log-based metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/) using that particular `JsonPayload`. Using Stackdriver logging, you can click on the `FailedGetResourceMetric` string and select "*Show matching entries*" to update your filter and once you have an accurate filter, you can create the metric.

When you have a log-based metric, you can create an [Alerting Policy](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/ui-conditions-ga) to match a condition based on your metric.

For instance, you can use the log-based metric to count the number of *occurences* (how many log entries are matching this `FailedGetResourceMetric`) to trigger a notification.

Stackdriver allows you to [send notification via various channels](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options), including emails, when creating these kind of policies.